# How to send data from iphone to MAC/PC via serial port?

Tags: iphone

I'm new to these things, and have no idea how to achieve this thing.
I want to send some data from iphone to MAC/PC and also want to receive data sent from MAC to iphone.
Please help me out or give me some clue, where I can start from.

Answer (score 1):

Most apps solve this issue by including a small http server in the app and providing a web interface to upload/download data to the app.